# How to open hyperlinks in a new tab/window

Tags: pdf.js

The default behaviour of PDF.js is to open hyperlinks in the existing window. However, this may not be the desired outcome at all times. How can we open hyperlinks in a new window/tab and override the default behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

There's a property called `PDFJS.externalLinkTarget`. This is set to `NONE` by default. Set this to `BLANK` and `target='_blank'` attributes are added to all anchors. That will open your hyperlinks in a new tab/window.

Possible values:

- NONE [default]
- SELF
- BLANK
- PARENT
- TOP

**[Docs](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/9f8d67475ea668e3e8eaeb241733b998d64e90ca/src/display/global.js#L217-L228)**

Answer (score 0):

In build/pdf.js, replace the line below:

```
target: data.newWindow ? _display_utils.LinkTarget.BLANK : linkService.externalLinkTarget,
```

With this one:

```
target: _display_utils.LinkTarget.BLANK,
```

And then all links will always open in a new tab. I suppose you could pass it as a parameter. I never looked into how, because I wanted it to be permanent anyway, so hard-coded it.